# Terraform - Azure: Attach Existing Disk - Changing property 'dataDisk.name' is not allowed

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-virtual-machine, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

**Environment:**

```
Terraform v0.11.0
+ provider.azurerm v0.3.3
+ provider.tls v1.0.1
```

**Problem:**

Trying to attach an existing disk on VM being provisioned, getting error as such:

```
* azurerm_virtual_machine.kafka_vm: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=409 Code="PropertyChangeNotAllowed" Message="Changing property 'dataDisk.name' is not allowed."
```

Here is `vm.tf`:

```
storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${var.env_short_name}-zookeeper-data01"
    managed_disk_id = "${var.kafka_data_image_id}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    disk_size_gb  = "30"
    lun             = 5
  }
```

..where `managed_disk_id` is a variable (i.e., `$var.kafka_data_image_id`) defined with a full path to the existing disk. Example:

```
kafka_data_image_id  = "/subscriptions/XXXXX-fcf3-4ec6-b598-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/TEST-Environment-test0001-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/test1-kafka-data01"
```

I tried to provide `""` for the name, but it errored out telling me that I must provide name. Any pointers on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `name` from your definition and it will work.

```
storage_data_disk {
    managed_disk_id = "${var.kafka_data_image_id}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    disk_size_gb    = "30"
    lun             = 5
}
```

Comment: Nope. Not working. It complains: Error: azurerm_virtual_machine.kafka_vm: "storage_data_disk.1.name": required field is not set

Comment: ok, i assume you are out of luck in this case. terraform is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

My mistake was to specify `disk_size_gb` bigger than the original (`20GB`). As a result, TF was giving me (may it was proxying the answer from Azure API?) as if name provided was bad. Thus, as long as `disk_size_gb` matches provided, existing disk size, the operation should be successful (yes, with the disk name kept in tact).